# Matlab- How to plot waveform selected by threshold value. (by fetching data from array) and plotting it

Tags: matlab, plot, draw, waveform, subplot

[20 wave forms fetched out of 1000](https://app.box.com/s/02s8wol9d9wokew5zdhk)I wanted to fetch waveform from array.
I am using following code.

```
clc
clear('all');
close('all');

Load ('w.mat'); % w.mat is actually file holding 1000 wave forms)

x= 1:length(w(1,:));

Subplot(321);
Plot(x,w(1:20,:)); %Plotting First 20 wave forms out of 1000
```

Now by visually looking at plot I found out that 0.6 is X axis threshold  and about 15 point mark is the Y axis Threshold ( I would have posted picture here but i am new to stack flow forum it is not allowing me to post it).

How can I fetch waveforms on basis of X Axis threshold of 0.6 and Y axis Index value of about 15. and stored them in different files.
I know Save command to save it into a file on basis of different arguments assigned to it. But How to access X Axis and Y Axis values and compare the waveforms.

I wanted to compare to wave 2 actually which is more close , any too high values i have to avoid.

Any help Idea, as I am from C++ background. Matlab is a bit new to me.
Thanks Heaps
Kind Regards
K Haroon

Comment: Firstly `x= 1:length(w(1,:));` should surely be `x= 1:length(w(:,1));`?? Either way it's better to do `x= 1:size(w,2);`

Comment: Secondly it's impossible to know what you're asking. Please make some mock data (like a 5x5 mock `w`) and manually calculate the output and show us what you want

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean with 'X/Y axis threshold'? Do you maybe mean roots or global minima?

Comment: Hi Dan, Actually this is a brain spikes file which has 1 wave form and 50 attributes associated to it.and column value in W(Row,Col) is used to store all those values. so for first Values it is(1,50) where first is the Row Number and 50 is a fix number. I checked with Data people and they said it needed to be plotted like that.
So what do you say about taking all values of column and plot by each Row waveform.I have uploaded the file in following site,you can see the parameters there.What I want is to gather similar wave form in one variable and plot.
https://app.box.com/s/31f8gzz3374ulyj9cc0y

Comment: Hi Fraukje
X and Y threshold just means a point on X and Y axis , to which these wave forms are going on. I wanted to find common ones. Means going to same height on X axis , and on Y Axis most of the occuring ones. if you click the hyper link above in question, where its says "20 wave forms extracted out of 1000"- it will show you a picture of waveform already plotted. So i wanted to separate them first for 20 samples and then apply same logic on more data with some kind of loop.
In Dan Answer I put a link as well, for the data file which i have, I checked its variables in work space as well

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are asking is how can we save the data whole value is greater than 0.6 on the x-axis and 15 on the y-axis 
you can store the data/matrix in a variable by using

```
data=load('filename.txt')
```

and then applying a condition on  its variables and then store them in a text-file using

```
dlmwrite('filename.txt',extracted_data_array)
```

if that's what you are asking

Comment: I don't think this answer covers the question very well. I think he is specifically asking HOW to do fetch data after loading it, maybe you can provide that in your answer?

Comment: Dear Johnny mate, I already load the file and its variables are in work space. if you click the hyperlink of question "20 waves forms extracted out of 1000"" -it will give you waveform graph. I wanted to extract the position of the graph up to which, the most waveforms are hitting. and same on Y axis. the position on X axis is called threshold, and on Y axis it is called index position.
Now there could be a way to find it from array position but i guess its too complex, easier is to use a matlab command for graph position judgement and then apply that criteria in some sort of loop.Any idea???

Comment: try this command find() for example you want to find a values of y less than 15,you can use it like this new_array=find(y<15) it will return you the indices of the values for which of y < 15